# Creating folder using php in root directory shows mkdir error in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php, mkdir

My issue is getting an error as following while try to create a folder using php script in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`.

> mkdir(): permission denied

Am am using ubuntu system and lampp installed. In my application I need to create a folder in `/opt/lampp/htdoc/` for temporary storage of files.

I can able to create files and folders dynamically by php script.

I have checked my folder owner and group and changed it to www-data:www-data as same as in inner folder, but still same error.

Here is my code for creating folder:

```
$old = umask(0); 
mkdir($UploadDirectory, 0777,true);
umask($old);
```

My `$UploadDirectory` path is also the correct `/opt/lampp/htdocs/mydirectory`.

I have tried all the available answers in StackOverflow, that's why I am creating new question. Please help.

Comment: Did you check your PHP configuration for whenever `safe_mode` or `basedir` is set? Where does the script that runs those commands reside? Why are you setting the `umask`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running ubuntu,  check out [AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) as this is likely what is preventing you writing.   You can run aa-logprof and follow the prompts.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed other sites with a few others that asked this question with varying answers that worked, none of which worked for me. I have included the answer that ended up working in my case. I hope this information will help some people at least.

The solution that did NOT work for me but might work for some people was:

```
$old = umask(0);
mkdir("/path/some_dir/", 0755, true);
umask($old);
```

The one that did work for me though with a somewhat peculiar behavior:

```
$old = umask(0000);
mkdir("/var/www/html/somewebsite/images/somefolder/somefolder/", 6640, true);
umask($old);
```

The created folders seem to end up with the 640 permissions.